# How to pass XML in Body of POST Request in React Native?

Tags: javascript, xml, fetch-api

Hello Guys I have made an React Native Application using Expo and I have a question regarding a **fetch** call.

Lets say this is my fetch call:

```
const getMonthReport = async () => {
  await fetch("http:/xxx/jasperserver/rest_v2/reportExecutions", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/xml",
      "Content-Type": "application/xml"
    },
    body: { ... } 
  });
}
```

How can I pass my XML as the body of the request? It looks like this:

```
<reportExecutionRequest>
    <reportUnitUri>/Test/MonthReport2</reportUnitUri>
    <async>false</async>
    <freshData>true</freshData>
    <saveDataSnapshot>false</saveDataSnapshot>
    <outputFormat>html</outputFormat>
    <interactive>false</interactive>
        <parameters>
        <reportParameter name="allHrs">
            <value>90:00</value>
        </reportParameter>
        <reportParameter name="holidayHrs">
            <value>07:36</value>
        </reportParameter>
        <reportParameter name="illHrs">
            <value>18:00</value>
        </reportParameter>
    </parameters>
</reportExecutionRequest>
```

Comment: Just pass the XML as a string... `body: \`<reportExecutionRequest>...</reportExecutionRequest>\``

Comment: ...but make sure the XML is well-formed, i.e. *passing it* as a string is fine, *building it* by concatenating strings will come and bite you. Use an XML DOM do build/manipulate the document.

Comment: Yeah that worked I tried it like that but with some brackets and JSON.stringify and didnt get any valid results but using it as Phil stated works! Thanks!